# Modify Constraint to be Filtered

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause, unique-constraint, unique-index

I'm looking into converting a pre-existing constraint in my database to a filtered constraint. This is the constraint as it exists presently:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ALIAS] ADD  CONSTRAINT [AK_ALIAS001] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [ASSIGNEDBY] ASC,
    [ROLETYPE] ASC,
    [CODEALIAS] ASC,
    [ALIASASSIGNEDBY] ASC
)

WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90)

ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

I would like to not lose the functionality, but now that I'm adding a new ALIASASSIGNEDBY value I need to be able to have non-unique values for these fields if the ALIASASSIGNEDBY is anything other than 1.

From my reading I think I should be able to make this constraint conditional, but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I'm reading your requirement, you want to enforce uniqueness on that tuple within the set where `ALIASASSIGNEDBY = 1` (and, by extension, if `ALIASASSIGNEDBY <> 1`, anything goes).

If I have the above correct, here's how I'd do it:

```
create unique index [UIX_ALIAS001] on [dbo].[ALIAS]
   ([ASSIGNEDBY], [ROLETYPE], [CODEALIAS], [ALIASASSIGNEDBY])
   WHERE [ALIASASSIGNEDBY] = 1;
```

A couple of notes:

1. Since this index now only applies to a subset of the data, queries that were using the previous index (implicitly created from the unique constraint) may no longer be able to use the new one. Something to check!
2. You may not need `[ALIASASSIGNEDBY]` as a key column in the index. The way I've defined it, all rows that qualify for the filter will have the same value and so it's redundant from the standpoint of enforcing uniqueness.
3. If you're on an edition of SQL that allows it, consider making this an online index creation so as to avoid locking the table for the duration.
4. If you're on an edition of SQL that allows it, consider adding data compression to the index. in my experience, it's almost always a Good Idea™.

Comment: Thank you for the detail! I'll look into points 3 & 4, for point 1, how do I go about testing that?

Comment: This is one case where just trying it is benign. If the features are enabled, it will allow you to proceed. If you're not, it will give you an error and not have made any change.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a unique filtered index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [IDX_ALIAS001] 
    ON [dbo].[ALIAS] ([ASSIGNEDBY], [ROLETYPE], [CODEALIAS], [ALIASASSIGNEDBY])
    WHERE [ALIASASSIGNEDBY] <> 1
```